# How do I add new element to JSON object in multiple places referring to an another element using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json

I have a Json response as follow with multiple repeated arrays and would need to add a new element&value in each array after "bcd" using javascript code.

```
{
    "id": "123",
    "discount": [
        {
            "abc": xx,
            "bcd": xxx,
             "mc": {
            "dca": "xx",
            },
            "typ": "xx",
            "state": "xx",
            "mns": []
        },

        {
        "abc": xxx,
        "bcd": xxx,
        "dca": "xxx",
        },
     ]
```

}

expected response:

```
{
    "id": "123",
    "discount": [
        {
            "abc": xx,
            "bcd": xxx,
            "newelement":new value,
             "mc": {
            "dca": "xx",
            },
            "typ": "xx",
            "state": "xx",
            "mns": []
        },

            {
            "abc": xxx,
            "bcd": xxx,
           "newelement":new value
            "dca": "xxx",
            },
         ]
}
```

Can anyone please suggest how to do this using JavaScript,

Comment: `object.discount.forEach(o => o[newElement] = newValue)`

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use

```
obj.discount.forEach(function(x) { x.newelement = "new value"; });
```

to iterate through your `discount` array and add a new property to all of its objects.

However, it won't guarantee the order and it actually should not. Even if one JSON serializer provides some way of ordering for properties, another will not.
JSON is not a string and not a text, is it primarily **data**.
JSON / JS object properties are not ordered - that's the main difference between arrays and objects.

Read more on this topic here: [Does JavaScript Guarantee Object Property Order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order)

In general, you should never rely on order of JSON object properties and should never expect someone to rely on it.

Answer (score 0):

You could map over the discounts array returning new objects with all the properties you want.

This has the benefit of breaking object references and mutability preventing any side effects throughout your code from mutating properties of a common object.

These patterns are equivalent, but the es6 version will currently only work with babel compilation.

```js
const data = {
  "id": "123",
  "discount": [
    { "abc": 'xx' },
    { "abc": 'xxx' }
  ]
}

// es5
data.discount = data.discount.map(function(x) {
  return Object.assign({}, x, {
    newElement: 'new value'
  })
})

// es6
data.discount = data.discount.map(x => ({
  ...x,
  newElement: 'new value'
}))

console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution to your problem. Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/tt92jkhx/

var test = {
    "id": "123",
    "discount": [
        {
            "abc": "xx",
            "bcd": "xx",
             "mc": {
            "dca": "xx",
            },
            "typ": "xx",
            "state": "xx",
            "mns": []
        }
     ]
     };

```
 for(var i=0;i<test.discount.length;i++){
   var disc = test.discount[i];
   disc['newElement']='SomeValue';      
 }

 console.log(test);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ES6` Array [**for...of**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop to iterate the `discount` array of an object to `add the property` in the each object of an array.

```js
var jsonObj = {
    "id": "123",
    "discount": [
        {
            "abc": "xx",
            "bcd": "xxx",
             "mc": {
            "dca": "xx",
            },
            "typ": "xx",
            "state": "xx",
            "mns": []
        },
        {
        "abc": "xxx",
        "bcd": "xxx",
        "dca": "xxx",
        },
     ]
};

for (var value of jsonObj.discount) {
  value.newelement = "new value";
}

console.log(jsonObj.discount);
```

As [yeldar-kurmangaliyev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3218692/yeldar-kurmangaliyev) said in his answer that JSON/JS object properties are not ordered. Hence, it won't guarantee the order.

check this post for more reference on object property order : https://stackoverflow.com/a/5525820/4116300